# How to generate Ctrl+v(Paste) like similar event from an android app?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to generate a Paste event in android. I have already read about "Keyevents" in android but till yet I have not found any key to generate paste event. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173733/paste-text-on-android-using-adb) stackoverflow question is also not helpful.

Even the accepted answer is not very clear. So is there any way to do this like by using any 3rd party library, etc. Please help

Comment: Its to copy the text not of paste.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager#19177644

Comment: @Klatschen Will it work if i have to paste text on Edittext  of any other app?

Comment: I think so, but I don't know it rigth now and cannot test it now :)

Comment: @Klatschen I have tried it but its not pasting text in any way, I have no idea why they have named it as a paste module. It is only to fetch the copied text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after a lot of research I have found one way to paste the copied text and that is by using [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService).

I got the solution while searching for one exception from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795662/cannot-perform-this-action-on-a-not-sealed-instance-java-lang-illegalstateexce) stackoverflow thread.

Still for a quick view I am pasting the code over here too, If you already have copied the text and your Accessibility Service is all set then you can just use this piece of code:

```
  @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
        if (source != null && ( event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED ) ) {

                try{
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE); 

        }
    }
```

I have added **Thread.sleep(2000)** to give sometime for UI to load and then paste text later.